# What's the significance of the Σ(1/pi^n)?

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, pi

I was recently interested in the formula

**equ 1**: $$\sum_{n=0}^∞ 1/2^n$$

This made me curious about:

**equ 2**: $$\sum_{n=0}^∞ \frac{1}{\pi^n}$$

I found that the second formula converges to 0.466942206924260.

Several google searches later, I couldn't find anything useful that referenced **equ 2** beyond these two articles: [article 1](https://www.kontrolnaya-rabota.ru/s/equal-one/uproschenie-vyirazhenij/znamenatel/expr/fedb95675629f98809452653ec8a79a3/) and [article 2](https://pi-profiling.info/abstract_documents/2015_dec_6_shane_findley_s_formula_stated_as_for_special_case_integers.pdf).

Is there anything mathematically meaningful about **equ 2** and its value?

By no means am I a mathematician :)

Comment: In general when $|r|<1$ you have $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty r^n = \dfrac{r}{1-r}$ which for $r=\pi^{-1}$ corresponds to $\dfrac{\pi^{-1}}{1-\pi^{-1}}$, or multiplying top and bottom by $\pi$ gives $\dfrac{1}{\pi-1}$.  See more about [geometric series on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: @JMoravitz, your comment could be an answer.

Comment: @lhf I gave no information or opinion on the usefulness of the specific sum in question, only generic information about sums *like* that.  Perhaps that specific sum and resulting value is useful in physics for springs or waves or something.  I interpret the question to be asking about the use of the specific sum as opposed to the generalized sum.

Comment: Thanks @JMoravtiz. Does that also mean that $\frac{1}{\pi -1}$ is the equivalent to $\frac{1}{\pi + e^{\pi*i}}$? I'm basing this on $e^{\pi*i}=-1$

Comment: Thank you @joriki for the suggestion. It's my first time posting here.

Comment: @haroldcampbell: Welcome! Good to see that you made good use of it :-)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by JMoravitz, the series in question is a geometric series and so its sum has a closed formula:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{\pi^n} = \frac{1}{1-\pi^{-1}} = \frac{\pi}{\pi-1} \approx 0.466942206924260\cdots
$$